# Degree of Solar Longitude vs Earth to calculate Equinox and Solstice ,etc

Tags: python, skyfield

I try build some function to calculate Solar longitude, commonly abbreviated as Ls, is the ecliptic longitude of the sun, i.e. the position of the sun on the celestial sphere along the ecliptic.

For example when input date 07/Nov/2021 it will return 225.08684077988164.
I search some lib on python but it mostly return date of Equinox.

I found some code to calculate it manually but also stuck on last row.

JD is Julian date ( After input Date + location , I will calculate it )

Final step for define degree

```
T = (JD - 2451545.0) / 36525

L0 = 280°.46645 + 36000°.76983*T + 0°.0003032*T2

M = 357°.52910 + 35999°.05030*T - 0°.0001559*T2 - 0°.00000048*T3

C = (1°.914600 - 0°.004817*T - 0°.000014*T2) * sin M + (0°.01993 - 0°.000101*T) * sin 2M + 0°.000290 * sin 3M

theta = L0 + C

lambda = theta - 0.00569 - 0.00478 * sin(125°.04 - 1934°.136*T)

**lambda = lambda - 360 * [lambda/360]**
```

But on last row  formula seem wrong because it always return 0

Comment: omitting the square brackets, which will raise syntax error, the last line boils down to: `lambda - 360 * lambda / 360 = lambda - lambda = 0`. So, yes, it does what you tell it to

Comment: Yes , I know because this formula I transform by some document I have read.
But it seem there is some typo mistake on that Document or square bracket have difference meaning as I assume.
So I am stuck on last step.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do the same thing in Skyfield (which you added as a tag, so I'm assuming you will welcome an answer that uses it), the “Coordinates in other reference frames” section of its documentation points to this method:

https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-position.html#skyfield.positionlib.ICRF.frame_latlon

Using that method with the Ecliptic reference frame, you would get:

```
from skyfield import api
from skyfield.framelib import ecliptic_frame

ts = api.load.timescale()
t = ts.utc(2021, 11, 7)
eph = api.load('de421.bsp')
astrometric = eph['Earth'].at(t).observe(eph['Sun'])
lat, lon, distance = astrometric.frame_latlon(ecliptic_frame)

print(lon.degrees)
```

To determine why its answer is slightly different, you would have to dig into all of Skyfield’s math, and all of the math in the equations that produced that number for you, and decide which math had higher precision and best reflected the true motions of the Earth and Sun.